# how to extract the compressed file into defined location using angularjs or any javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, blob, arraybuffer

I have hosted one Folder in local IIS,the folder which includes compressed files.

When i'm making http request to that hosted url, it is automatically downloaded into default location i.e. Downloads.

I want to select the destination path for that file saving path and before saving into that destination path it should extracted.

Tell me any approach which should be client side like javascript, angularjs, etc,.

Can any one tell me how to do this
Thanks in advance.

Please follow below which i have wrote in my application. 
Any one can update the below code or propose new approach.

```js
  $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:1234/' + filename+'.zip',
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers) {
            headers = headers();            
            var contentType = headers['content-type'];
            var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
            try {
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType});                 var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
                linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);
                linkElement.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                linkElement.click();                
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            }
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Comment: Do you want to manually select the location instead of default location before downloading the file?

Comment: yes, i want to give manually . and one more thing was it should extract and save into the location.